# How to get the Footer width to reach full screen

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I am making a website for a club and need help fixing the footer.

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: #222;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer-section {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-section">Contact us at : 1015 7th street NW <br>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-section">Hey how you doing</div>
  <div class="footer-section">This weezy F baby</div>
</footer>
```

I want my footer to reach full browser screen but a tiny part of it on the right is left out and shows my background. I feel it's because using 33% on the width when there's three columns that 1% is showing. Is there anyway to fix this and keep it responsive

Comment: use @media query to make it responsive. :)

Comment: have you tried removing the default margin on the `body`? i.e. `body {margin: 0; }`

Comment: @zgood Can he not set it to negative ? `body {margin: -10px;}`

Answer (score 1):

Try
**width: calc(100% / 3);**

instead of 
**width: 33%;**

Answer (score 0):

you can use grid layout to create perfect `1/3`.

```
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

---

```css
body{
  margin:0
}

footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  background: #222;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.footer-section {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-section">Contact us at : 1015 7th street NW <br>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-section">Hey how you doing</div>
  <div class="footer-section">This weezy F baby</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Margin is still there... :-(

Comment: @MarcoS OK I add style of body, but it does not look like OP have same problem (since OP says only right margin, no left)

Comment: @MarcoS OP: *a tiny part of it on the right is left out and shows my background*, I think you get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following will enable a full width footer.

```
* {
  margin:0;
}
.footer-section {
  width:33.33%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r1ev5tjg/

Edit:

It's best to look into using media queries if you're wanting to build a fully responsive website. That way you're able to set the width of each column depending on the screen size (Making each column full width on mobile screens for example).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_three_columns.asp

```
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


<div class="row">
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

modify the css with
CSS:-

```
* {
      margin:0;
    }

    footer {
      width: 100%;
      background: #222;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .footer-section {
      float: left;
      width: 33.33%;
      background: #222;
      color: white;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use `vw` = view width to set the elements width. 100vw is 100% of the view width, which is the window size.

```
.footer {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: Only problem with this is it creates a scrollbar. I would like to keep the page less clustered then possible

Comment: Add `margin: 0;` to the `body` in CSS